# Fuzzy autocomplete textbox control in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, postback, partial-postback

What is the best approximation algorithm to implement full-text fuzzy search. For example we have a dropdownlist with the following data (from SQL datasource):

- Company Policy
- Product Catelog
- Our Partners

Now I want to replace it with an autocomplete textbox, such that when the letter "p" is typed the list shows all three results. It should start matching the first letter of the first word or second word and so on. Also, it should highlight or make the matched letters bold in the suggestions dropdown.

Is there a readymade control for ASP.NET (with JS or jQuery) to deliver all the aforementioned functionality? Otherwise if I have to implement it, is there a tutorial/blog which point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I believe [this](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox) is what you're looking for.

It's jquery ui it has the autocomplete functionality described.

Comment: True, but if the option have multiple words this will fail. I need it to match with all the words in the phrase not just the first one.

Answer (score 0):

check out this one, I used it and works very well

http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx